# How to return any type of class in a method?

Tags: java, android, object, parsing, gson

I'm trying to do a function to return an specific type of object if it is an instance of one of them when I'm getting it from a json. How I can return a Generic Type in the method?

```
public Class<?> parseBody(String responseBody){
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    JsonObject bodyParsed = JsonParser.parseString(responseBody).getAsJsonObject();

    if (bodyParsed.has("OS") && bodyParsed.has("version")) {
        return (DeviceInfoDto) gson.fromJson(bodyParsed, DeviceInfoDto.class);
    }else if (bodyParsed.has("result") && bodyParsed.has("operationToken")) {
        return (OperationTokenDto) gson.fromJson(bodyParsed, OperationTokenDto.class);
    }else if (bodyParsed.has("result") && bodyParsed.has("userUUID")) {
        return (UserIDTokenDto) gson.fromJson(bodyParsed, UserIDTokenDto.class);
    }else if (bodyParsed.has("result")) {
        return (ResultDto) gson.fromJson(bodyParsed, ResultDto.class);
    }
    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This approach has many disadvantages: 1) No need to create Gson instances every time you invoke the method. 2) No need to collect everything into a probably big string (consider using I/O streams instead). 3) Usually no need to parse _entire_ payload into a JSON element: this can be easily delegated to your custom type adapter (see RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory that uses a similar but limited approach -- yours would be a super-set of it); 4) There is no sense returning `Class<?>` in your case: it represents a class, not a class intance.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's actually a `Class<?>` that those methods are returning, return `Object`.

```
public Object parseBody(String responseBody){
```

or a more-specific common supertype of the `*Dto` classes, if one exists:

```
public BaseDto parseBody(String responseBody){
```

You can't return "the type it is", because the "type it is" depends on data derived from the `String responseBody`. There's no type information in the parameters to allow you to return, say, `DeviceInfoDto`.